# Cannot resolve symbol 'services' import com.google.api.services;

Tags: java, android, google-api-java-client

I am trying to follow [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java) sample for google-api-java-client for android app but in my andoid project it is not resolving the symbol **services** and **drive**. I downloaded the lib files of [google-api-java-client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download) and copied it to the apps lib folder.

Included following to app build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev134-1.23.0'
```

and added the following to project build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

but still I am getting the error that can not resolve the symbol.

Comment: post your full error logcat.

Comment: It shows error when I import com.google.api.services in a class